# User search via Instagram API in SandBox mode returns only my (owner) user

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm developing small instagram-module for my web-site and at the beginning I have only SandBox mode permissions so I can only search for photos by tag in my account or three other accounts I have added to the Sandbox Users and they accepted. Search by tag works properly but when I'm trying to search by author I can only get my own account info but not any of my other Sandbox Users.
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=tanas&access_token=MYTOKEN

I need to search through all of the public users in my  Sandbox Users list.

Comment: does the other 3 accounts have "tanas" in the name ?

Comment: @krisrak off-course

Comment: Looks like they have fixed an API. It works now.

Comment: Hi franky...I'm facing the same issue...did yours get resolved?

Comment: @MohammedAzhar No, it was fixed by itself